# jQuery DataTable Not Working In Asp.net WebForm From MasterPage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, webforms, datatables

I Have A Problem With Using jQuery dataTable in A WebForm From Master Page

Every Time I Write The JavaScript Required To Enable jQuery dataTable Nothing Happens

Anyone knows how to make this jQuery Table Works Inside Content Place Holder

Thanks

```js
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrimeHealth_Network.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                                                <th>Browser</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <asp:ListView ID="AllLocationsList" runat="server">
                                                    <itemtemplate>
                                                         <tr>
                                                              <td><%#Eval("LocID")%></td>
                                                                <td><%#Eval("LocationName")%></td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                    </itemtemplate>
                                            </asp:ListView>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <!-- DATA TABLE SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dataTables-example').dataTable().Editable();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Well, I do not think anyone in the world is able to answer on "_Every Time I Write The Java Script Requered To Enable jQuery Datatable Nothing Happens_" without seeing the actual code you are using.

Comment: Are you sure all the script references are relative to the .aspx page that they are being called from and not the .master?

Comment: Yes i am sure that every thing is up and workign